# Routes with controllers: In route or template definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

When defining a route with a template, there's basically two ways how you can set the controller corresponding to the view:

- In the route:

  ```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/phone/:phoneId', {
       controller: 'PhoneDetailController',
       templateUrl: 'phone.detail.html',
       }
  });
  ```
- In the template:

  ```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/phone/:phoneId', {
       templateUrl: 'phone.detail.html',
       }
  });
  ```

  ```
  <div ng-controller="PhoneDetailController">
    <!-- [...] -->
  </div>
  ```

What are the differences, what is recommended, and why?

Comment: I have not seem the second option being used as much, first option is pretty standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the ui-router source code, inside [viewDirective.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js) you can see how the controller is instantiated:

```
if (locals.$$controller) {
    locals.$scope = scope;
    locals.$element = $element;
    var controller = $controller(locals.$$controller, locals);
    if (locals.$$controllerAs) {
        scope[locals.$$controllerAs] = controller;
    }
    $element.data('$ngControllerController', controller);
    $element.children().data('$ngControllerController', controller);
}
```

So basically your two options are going to do essentially the same thing. So it is up to you, and what you believe the best semantics to be. Personally I prefer to put my controller names inside the state def, as I like to keep my templates as view oriented (and reusable) as possible. Also it seems to be the most common way to do things, so others will be able to understand your code more easily.

Comment: We're not using the ui-router, but I get the gist. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. But yes, it is approximately the same concept. On that note, I *never* use the built in router, and always opt for ui-router for my angular projects. It is much nicer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the first version because of the better and central configuration. I think there is not a big difference but like in Comment from Filype I did not see Version 2 that often.